# Specifically using DateUtils, how do I format a numeric date with no year

Tags: android, android-dateutils

I want to format a date string to not have a year (Ex: "1/4").

```
int flags = DateUtils.FORMAT_NUMERIC_DATE | DateUtils.FORMAT_NO_YEAR;
```

The above flags still append a year to the date (Ex: "1/4/2016").  How do I drop the year?

Comment: don´t really know if it helps, but try to set the flag: DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE | DateUtils.FORMAT_NUMERIC_DATE | DateUtils.FORMAT_NO_YEAR); (with the format show date too)

Comment: I'm getting the same result.  Possibly a bug in Android 4.1?

Comment: I read some posts about Bugs with DateUtils since  4.0 ... maybe that´s the point...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that date formatting changed after 4.4 Android version:

For 4.1 Android version [DateUtils.formatDateTime](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/text/format/DateUtils.java#DateUtils.formatDateTime%28android.content.Context%2Clong%2Cint%29) goes up to [DateUtils.formatDateRange](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/text/format/DateUtils.java#DateUtils.formatDateRange%28android.content.Context%2Cjava.util.Formatter%2Clong%2Clong%2Cint%2Cjava.lang.String%29) where the string is formatted using Formatter.

But from 4.4 Android version [DateUtils.formatDateRange](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.1_r1/android/text/format/DateUtils.java#DateUtils.formatDateRange%28android.content.Context%2Cjava.util.Formatter%2Clong%2Clong%2Cint%2Cjava.lang.String%29) uses `libcore.icu.DateIntervalFormat` to format a String.

```
public static Formatter formatDateRange(Context context, Formatter formatter, long startMillis,
                                        long endMillis, int flags, String timeZone) {
    // If we're being asked to format a time without being explicitly told whether to use
    // the 12- or 24-hour clock, icu4c will fall back to the locale's preferred 12/24 format,
    // but we want to fall back to the user's preference.
    if ((flags & (FORMAT_SHOW_TIME | FORMAT_12HOUR | FORMAT_24HOUR)) == FORMAT_SHOW_TIME) {
        flags |= DateFormat.is24HourFormat(context) ? FORMAT_24HOUR : FORMAT_12HOUR;
    }

    String range = DateIntervalFormat.formatDateRange(startMillis, endMillis, flags, timeZone);
    try {
        formatter.out().append(range);
    } catch (IOException impossible) {
        throw new AssertionError(impossible);
    }
    return formatter;
}
```

So you have to trim a resulting String or use DateFormat/SimpleDateFormat to remove year field on 4.1 Android.

---

Answer (score 2):

This works well for me

```
 int flags =  DateUtils.FORMAT_NUMERIC_DATE | DateUtils.FORMAT_NO_YEAR;
 String s = DateUtils.formatDateTime(this, System.currentTimeMillis(), flags);
```

Comment: I'm doing exactly this on Android 4.1 and it is still showing me a year.

Comment: What version of Android are you running?

Comment: Check out the answer I approved.  It seems pre-4.4 does things a little differently.  Thank you for your help though.  I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a SimpleDateFromat. Something like this:

```
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd");
String dateString = df.format(date);
```

Comment: It´s correct, but the OP asked espacially for DateUtils

Comment: Yeah, you right. Sorry, just wanted to help. Should hade read the q more carefully